# Running dd. Why resource is busy?

Tags: osx, dd, sd-card, resources

I just formatted microSD card, and would like to run a `dd` command. Unfortunately `dd` command fails:

```
$ sudo dd bs=1m if=2016-02-26-raspbian-jessie-lite.img of=/dev/rdisk2
dd: /dev/rdisk2: Resource busy
$
```

Everyone on the internet says I need to unmount the disk first. Sure, can do that and move on. But **I want to understand why / what exactly in OS X is making the device busy**? How do I diagnose this?

So far I tried:

1. Listing open files:

   ```
   $ lsof /dev/disk2
   $ lsof /dev/disk2s1
   $
   ```

   Also:

   ```
   $ lsof /Volumes/UNTITLED
   $
   ```
2. Listing users working on the file:

   ```
   $ fuser -u /dev/disk2
   /dev/disk2: 
   $ fuser -u /dev/disk2s1 
   /dev/disk2s1:
   $
   ```

   Also:

   ```
   $ fuser -u /Volumes/UNTITLED
   $
   ```
3. Check for system messages:

   ```
   $ sudo dmesg | grep disk
   $
   ```

   Also:

   ```
   $ sudo dmesg | grep /Volumes/UNTITLED
   $
   ```

My environment

1. Operating system:

   ```
   Darwin Eugenes-MacBook-Pro-2.local 15.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0: Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
   ```
2. Information about my microSD:

   ```
   diskutil list disk2
   /dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *31.9 GB    disk2
      1:                 DOS_FAT_32 UNTITLED                31.9 GB    disk2s1
   ```

P.S. I'm using OS X 10.11.

**Update 22/3/2016**. Figured it out. I re-ran the `lsof` and `fuser` from above using `sudo`, and finally got to the bottom of the issue:

```
$ sudo fuser /Volumes/UNTITLED/
/Volumes/UNTITLED/: 62 282
$
```

And:

```
$ sudo lsof /Volumes/UNTITLED/
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
mds        62 root    8r   DIR    1,6    32768         2 /Volumes/UNTITLED
mds        62 root   22r   DIR    1,6    32768         2 /Volumes/UNTITLED
mds        62 root   23r   DIR    1,6    32768        10 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD
mds        62 root   25u   REG    1,6        0 999999999 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD/journalExclusion
mds_store 282 root  txt    REG    1,6     3277        17 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD/0.indexGroups
mds_store 282 root  txt    REG    1,6        8        23 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD/0.indexCompactDirectory
mds_store 282 root  txt    REG    1,6      312        19 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD/0.indexTermIds
mds_store 282 root  txt    REG    1,6     3277        29 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD/live.0.indexGroups
mds_store 282 root  txt    REG    1,6     1024        35 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD/live.0.indexCompactDirectory
mds_store 282 root  txt    REG    1,6      312        21 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD/0.indexPositionTable
mds_store 282 root  txt    REG    1,6     8192        31 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD/live.0.indexTermIds
mds_store 282 root  txt    REG    1,6     2056        22 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD/0.indexDirectory
mds_store 282 root  txt    REG    1,6     8192        33 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD/live.0.indexPositionTable
mds_store 282 root  txt    REG    1,6     8224        34 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD/live.0.indexDirectory
mds_store 282 root  txt    REG    1,6       16        16 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD/0.indexIds
mds_store 282 root  txt    REG    1,6    65536        48 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD/reverseDirectoryStore
mds_store 282 root  txt    REG    1,6      704        24 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD/0.indexArrays
mds_store 282 root  txt    REG    1,6    65536        26 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD/0.directoryStoreFile
mds_store 282 root  txt    REG    1,6    32768        28 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD/live.0.indexIds
mds_store 282 root  txt    REG    1,6    65536        36 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD/live.0.indexArrays
mds_store 282 root  txt    REG    1,6    65536        38 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD/live.0.directoryStoreFile
mds_store 282 root    5r   DIR    1,6    32768        10 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD
mds_store 282 root   17u   REG    1,6     8192        12 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD/psid.db
mds_store 282 root   32r   DIR    1,6    32768        10 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD
mds_store 282 root   41u   REG    1,6       28        15 /Volumes/UNTITLED/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V2/A2D41CCB-48CC-45F3-B8D6-F3B383D91AAD/indexState
$
```

From the above it's easy to see that processes called `mds` and `mds_store` have created and are *holding* lots of files on the volume.

Comment: Use `of=/dev/rdisk2` it is so much faster, and not so taxing to your SD card.

Comment: Hi @RuiFRibeiro! Yeah, that makes total sense, I forgot about `rdisk` when writing this.

Comment: The device is busy because it is automounted...; you umount it, do your dd, and it will get automounted again as soon as dd finishes.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I know, that make sense... But is there some other indication, apart from seeing `/Volumes/UNTITLED` and _knowing_ it's automounted? Like, some logs, or some better some process responsible for _taking_ the device?

Comment: http://www.apple.com/business/docs/Autofs.pdf

Comment: hmmm maybe com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro turns out there are 2 processes currently _holding_ the mounted volume. What I missed was running `lsof` and `fuser` with root privileges. After running both with `sudo`, I figured processes called `mds` and `mds_store` created over a dozen of files on the volume.

Comment: spotlight running?

Comment: yep http://9to5mac.com/2014/02/11/how-to-get-spotlight-processes-back-under-control-when-cpu-usage-goes-crazy/

Comment: disable it expressly with mdutil for your cards/pens/external disks...

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro yup, exactly

Comment: This answer helped me! https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9217/resource-busy-error-when-using-dd-to-copy-disk-img-to-sd-card

Comment: You appear to have answered the question with an edit to the question rather than with an actual answer (using the answer box at the bottom of the page). I suggest that if you ever come back here, move that text into a proper answer and then accept that answer. As it currently stands, you appear to have accepted an answer that does not actually answer the question (why is unmounting necessary).

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Apple court, Apple rules. Try `diskutil`:

```
$ diskutil list
...

# if mounted somewhere
$ sudo diskutil unmount $device

# all the partitions (there's also a "force" option, see the manual)
$ sudo diskutil unmountDisk $device

# remember zip drives? this would launch them. good times!
$ sudo diskutil eject $device
```

(In the case of a disk image, the `hdiutil` command may also be of interest. You can also click around in `Disk Utility.app`.)

Comment: Hi @thrig, thank you. Yes, I am able to unmount using `diskutil`, no problem with that. What I'm doing here is I'm learning how to identify problems in the system by saying "Yes" to any warning I can spot. I want to know why "Resource busy" is happening in the first place, not how to get rid of it. What exact process in the OS is making this happen?

Comment: @gmile the kernel, as far as I know, locks busy devices, so you need to unmount and eject any partition and image to remove that kernel lock.

Comment: oh, this is interesting. I'm going to google for kernel locking now. Maybe you have some good resource on your mind where I could read about it?

Comment: If '''sudo diskutil unmount''' doesn't work, check here (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9217/resource-busy-error-when-using-dd-to-copy-disk-img-to-sd-card)

Answer (score 33):

Unmounting the sub partitions helped

```
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *8.0 GB     disk2
   1:             Windows_FAT_16 wr_usb_efi              134.2 MB   disk2s1
   2:                      Linux                         1.1 GB     disk2s2
vgsprasad-mbp:~ vgsprasad$ diskutil umount /dev/disk2s1
Volume wr_usb_efi on disk2s1 unmounted
vgsprasad-mbp:~ vgsprasad$ diskutil umount /dev/disk2s2
disk2s2 was already unmounted
```

Comment: aside from missing formatting, the OP specifically said "Everyone on the internet says I need to unmount the disk first. Sure, can do that and move on. But I want to understand why / what exactly in OS X is making the device busy?"

Comment: @Jeff I ran into the same problem as gmile, I was aiming to write an .iso to a USB stick, and dd returned `dd: /dev/disk9: Resource busy`. When I unmounted with `diskutil umount /dev/disk9s1`, the device disappeared from the desktop, but the `/dev/disk9` was still mounted so `dd` couldn't perform as it should. So Mac OSX kept the device busy by creating a short-cut to the USB stick's inner filesystem.